# Android Studio - Animation UI

Tags: android, animation

I've just started my work with android and android studio. I've never created any apps for android. I'd like to add some animations to my project. Before I did it in Expression Blend (Windows Phone 8). How can I do it for Android?

Comment: what have you tried? you can do animations via xml, programmatically or even with canvas.

Comment: i'd like to make animation via "drag and drop" - like Expression Blend (timeline, move object, key frames etc)

Answer (score 0):

Android supports OpenGL.

This link from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html) describes OpenGL's uage for animation and graphics within Android:

"OpenGL
Android supports OpenGL ES 1.0 and 2.0, with Android framework APIs as well as natively with the Native Development Kit (NDK). Using the framework APIs is desireable when you want to add a few graphical enhancements to your application that are not supported with the Canvas APIs, or if you desire platform independence and don't demand high performance."

Also see [this Android Developer's page](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html) for simple UI animation.